# GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006] problem?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, google-data-api

II had been working on my project like normal when all of a sudden I got this error:

```
> 2020-05-20 01:42:40.798198-0400 [10404:4763011] [GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006] There was an error reading extension bytes from disk: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “event-16738913419221216480” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B3D1204C-A52F-496C-89D8-388D4A75C102/Library/Caches/google-sdks-events/event-16738913419221216480, NSUnderlyingError=0x2838cdbf0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

The error occures in the file seen bellow.

[image]
The specific line error is:

```
> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16bcfffb0)
```

For the second line here:

```
NSString *pathString = [self
decodePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", originalPathString]]; //this line
FPath *path = [[FPath alloc] initWith:pathString];
FRepoInfo *repoInfo = [[FRepoInfo alloc] initWithHost:host
                                             isSecure:secure
                                        withNamespace:namespace];

FFLog(@"I-RDB095002", @"---> Parsed (%@) to: (%@,%@); ns=(%@); path=(%@)",
      url, [repoInfo description], [repoInfo connectionURL],
      repoInfo.namespace, [path description]);

FParsedUrl *parsedUrl = [[FParsedUrl alloc] init];
parsedUrl.repoInfo = repoInfo;
parsedUrl.path = path;

return parsedUrl;
```

I tried removing my pods and re-installing them. This did not change anything.

I have also tried restarting my computer.

**How can I solve this problem?**

**Update:**

After further testing, I found that the error occurs in various files within the firebaseDatabase folder, I also was able to isolate it to one query to the database found in multiple files. However under files after un-commenting it, it began working as before again. Given the number of queries however I still have the issue.

Also have an issue active on giithub: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5661.

Answer (score 1):

Run `pod update`

This issue was fixed a few weeks ago. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5421

Comment: Got passed that hurtle but now am getting this: ld: 460 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Been looking around but cant seem to find a solution

Comment: After trying to solve this other problem. Deintegrating then installing pods again. I got old issue. I then tried this solution again for it. And it now does not work... Im literally going to give myself a haircut with my bare hands.